# Android simplest VideoView sample can't run

Tags: android, resources, android-videoview

```
public class Tvdiplay1 extends Activity {      
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {          
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);           
        setContentView(R.layout.tvdisplay);           
        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.tvvideoView);          
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);          
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);          
        Uri video = Uri.parse("android-resource://" + R.raw.movie);          
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);          
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);          
        videoView.start(); 
    } 
}
```

The screen displays "Sorry the video cannot be played", 
after checking the movie in the device - it works in other players
I can only imagine that the problem is in the path.

Currently it has problems with R.raw.movie which isn't recognized by the compiler
although it was generated in the R class file. I can see the constant, i just can use it.

I'm really clueless about this problem, so please help !

Comment: This link may be helpful: http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/how-to-play-a-video-file/

Answer (score 1):

Context.getPackageName() in the path will help you!